# RequireJS strange undefined module

Tags: requirejs, amd

I am having an issue with an undefined variable in my module set up, best to explain by example, I have:

**common.js (config for requirejs)**

```
require([
    'module/polyfills/someModule'
], function(
    module
) {

    module.init();

});
```

**module/polyfills/someModule.js**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'config',
    'text!tpl/utils/textTemplate.html'
    ], function(_, config, template) {

    // ref 1
    return {
        init: function() {
            // ref 2
            // do stuff
        },

        events: function() {
            // add some events
        },

    };
});
```

If I put a breakpoint at the comment `ref 1` I can see the `config` variable and its properties. However if I put a breakpoint at `ref 2` then `config` is undefined. However underscore and the template are not undefined.

I have removed anything special about config in my require configuration. Config looks like this:

**config.js**

```
define([], function (clickType) {
    return {
        clickType: 'test'
    };
});
```

There are no errors in console and I am very certain this is not a circular dependency!

Comment: In what browser does this happen? And please add the complete code of `init` to your question.

Comment: ^+1, you might be using template inside your init, because of which it becomes available forming the closure. And that may not be case with config.

Answer (score 0):

the comment place at ref2 is a closure where you haven't accessed config. The function is created at parse and it is a closure, whatever you access inside it is available. simple test, add the following line of code at //ref2

```
var myConfig = config;
```

Now you will see config as defined.

Comment: I know that this will work, but what I don't understand is that at `ref 2` I am able to access both `_` and `template`.

Comment: _ can be explained... it adds itself to the global variable scope when executed... template however is surprising...